# How to capture raw/plain text response from the server

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm currently using Retrofit 1
[image]

I'm trying to find away to capture raw/plaintext response from server but not sure how to retrieve it.

This where i initialize it

```
    @POST(ApplicationConstants.USER_URL+"/resendActivationEmail")
    void resendEmail(@Body String email, ResponseCallback result);
```

and here's where i implement it.

```
userServiceApi.resendEmail(email, new ResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response response) {
                        LogHelper.debug("");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        LogHelper.debug(error.getMessage);

                    }
                });
```

what i get from     error.getMessage is only the http code status.

if i try to test the api with postman, this will be the response that i capture in JSON format

[image]

and this one will be in the raw/plain text format.

[image]

This is the client initialize

```
OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new PublicApiIntercepter()).build();
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ApplicationConstants.BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new Ok3Client(mClient))
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
            .build();
```

Please help. thank you

Comment: What is the value of http code? Check the value of error.getBody().

Comment: @JaysonChacko for error.getMessage == 401 and error.getBody == Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. But if i checked on postman for raw response == "e-mail address not registered"

Answer (score 0):

Change from :

```
@POST(ApplicationConstants.USER_URL+"/resendActivationEmail")
    void resendEmail(@Body String email, ResponseCallback result);
```

change to :

```
 @POST(ApplicationConstants.USER_URL+"/resendActivationEmail")
        Call<ResponseBody> resendEmail(@Body String email, ResponseCallback result);
```

Comment: I think Call<ResponseBody> only supported in Retrofit2 and its not supported for Retrofit1 @divaP